# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) : on Macbook

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gcc, terminal

I used the "gcc" command in the terminal before and ran the commands successfully. But today, whenever I run gcc , .cpp this shows the error like "error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

This is for all cpp files not for one.

Comment: I would expect an additional error message from the linker about why it failed. That message should be part of the question.

Comment: Use g++, not gcc.

Comment: compile with the -v flag and check the message it gives. Probably, some library is missing.

Comment: using g++ instead of gcc worked

Comment: As new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. There's much to improve in your question and the second link details this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The GCC compiler suite contains different commands for compiling C and C++ code. If you use the wrong one perhaps you would expect the compiler to give an error like this:

> This is not a C file.

But as you found out the hard way, this is not the case.¨

**`gcc`** is the compiler for C code and **`g++`** is the compiler for C++ code. And if you try to compile C++ using `gcc` you get an error like this:

```
$ gcc hello.cpp 
/tmp/cc9uZOKP.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `std::cout'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char)'
/tmp/cc9uZOKP.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```